# How to fix postgresql add extension cache lookup failed

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

Attempt to add pgcrypto extension failed with "Cache lookup failed for function 1, SQL xtate: XX000"

This is postgresql 11 running on Ubuntu 18.04.  This database instance has been running without any other noticeable problem for over a year.  Why do I get this error, preventing me from loading any extension, not just pgcrypto?

"select * from pg_extension;"  returns a single extension "plpgsql".

"select * from pg_available_extensions;"  returns a long list including pgcrypto.

Does this mean that the contribs are installed, yet something else is causing the error, or does it indicate an error in the contrib installation?  Is there a way to repair whatever is doing this?

Comment: See [cache lookup failed for function 1 on fmgr_info_cxt_security, fmgr.c:184](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/b7082510-b2a1-acbe-dc79-d4492eccacc4%40gmail.com)

Comment: Which is the same question, unanswered.

Comment: I'm not sure you read just the question or the whole thread, which says how to fix it by updating pg_language (but just not how/why the problem happened in the first place).

Comment: My apologies, I missed the response.  I also had a lanvalidator value of '1'.  I haven't messed with anything in the database following the initial install, so have no idea why it would be in error.  Nonetheless, I updated the value to 2247 and it solved the problem.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,

```
=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for function 1

=# select lanvalidator from pg_language where lanname='c';
 lanvalidator 
--------------
            1
(1 row)
```

The solution was the same as OP found in the [thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/b7082510-b2a1-acbe-dc79-d4492eccacc4%40gmail.com),

```
update pg_language set lanvalidator = 2247 where lanname = 'c';
```

After that, running the original command worked,

```
=# CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
CREATE EXTENSION
=#
```

Postgresql gets into this state after connecting via sqlalchemy to create a new database, load some data, drop another database and rename the newly created one. I do not know which of those steps did it.